# create pdf of rows in a database on a new page

Tags: php, pdf-generation

i am creating a student management system and i want to be able to generate a pdf report that will contain every students data in its own page i.e . studentId, Math, English, Science, Class, totals, Rank, myClass and  myTotals.for example, in the table below i would expect the pdf to have 6 pages. each containing only details of a particular student. how do i go about doing this?

Thank you in advance

```
studentId  Math  English  Science  Class  totals  Rank  myClass  myTotals
2          75    83       84       3p1    242     1     3p1      242
5          88    77       77       3p1    242     1     3p1      242
1          80    66       85       3p1    231     2     3p1      231
6          92    97       96       5p2    285     1     5p2      285
3          70    88       90       5p2    248     2     5p2      248
4          50    82       50       5p2    182     3     5p2      182
```

Comment: So do you want one row per page?

Comment: If you're comfortable with writing HTML, you can try one of the many [HTML to PDF converters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628).

Answer (score 0):

loop through the rows and create a new page for every row. How to do that exactly depends on with what you create the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could output the information to a LaTeX file (assuming the machine has it installed). I assume you get all your student details from a database into an array of arrays called `students`. If you are using mySQL or similar to store the data, this should be simple enough.

This should generate a `report.tex` file and then execute pdflatex to generate `report.pdf` file.

```
<?

$f = fopen('report.tex','w');
$out = '\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\begin{document}
';
fwrite($f,$out);
//Example array
$students = array(array('studentId'=> 1, 'Math'=> 1, 'English'=> 5 , 'Science' => 5, 'Class' =>6, 'totals'=>6 , 'Rank'=>7 , 'myClass' =>7, 'myTotals'=>9));
foreach($students as $x){
    $out = '\begin{table}[htbp]'."\n".' \centering'."\n";
    $out .= '\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}'."\n";
    $out .= '\hline'."\n";
    $out .= 'studentId & Math & English & Science & Class & totals & Rank & myClass & myTotals \\\\ '."\n \\hline \n";

    $out .= "{$x['studentId']} & {$x['Math']} &  {$x['English']} & {$x['Science']} & {$x['Class']} & {$x['totals']} & {$x['Rank']} & {$x['myClass']} & {$x['myTotals']} ";
    $out .= '\\\\'."\n \\hline";
    $out .= '\end{tabular} '."\n".' \end{table}'."\n".'\newpage' ."\n";
    fwrite($f,$out);

}
fwrite($f,"\n".'\end{document}');
fclose($f);
echo (exec('pdflatex report.tex'));
echo "\ndone";
?>
```

The script works properly now, that produces a correct file. Having the server send the pdf to you shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: i have tried working with LaTeX and installing it but i have been unable to make the script run. if possible i would appreciate a script that uses fpdf to generate the reports.

Comment: @hila, I have fixed and tested the script. It should work now using pdflatex. You might want to add in some extra stuff to download the produced pdf for you.